# Rails 5 rendering from outside a controller with ApplicationController.renderer.render doesn't set variables on self

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using the Rails 5 `ApplicationController.renderer.render` method to render from within a model.  I need to pass some variables to my layout which I have done using the `locals` option; this variable is then available in the layout if accessed directly, but not via `self`.

Here is how I have setup my render

```
html_string = ApplicationController.renderer.render(
  file: "/#{template_path}/base/show",
  :formats => [:pdf,:html],
  locals: {
    :@routing_form => self,
    :controller_name => controller_name,
    :action_name => action_name,
    :current_user => current_user
  },
  :layout  => '/layouts/application'
)
```

Then within the layout I want to do something like this.

```
<div id="foo" class="<%= self.action_name %>">
```

I was able to get this working by dropping `self` in this particular instance

```
<div id="foo" class="<%= action_name %>">
```

but now my concern is how would I set a variable so that it would work correctly with `self`?  Previously I was using the render_anywhere gem and this was handled  using `rendering_controller.var = "value"`

Comment: What class does `self` belongs to? I infer that `self` object doesn't have the methods `controller_name`, `action_name` and `current_user` (is it a Controller?), thus falling for you (you said you are rendering from "within a Model")

Comment: Have you tried `assigns` instead of `locals`?

Comment: @AlexN, yes; that has no impact on this particular issue.

Answer (score 3):

Since `self` is a keyword in Ruby, you cannot use it as a method call in your layout template, so you should use another name to pass with the locals.

You can pass something like `my_object: self` and it will work fine.

If you want to name the key with a @, you should put it inside a string `'@my_object': self` and calls it normally in your template: `<%= @my_object.action_name%>`

Comment: I think you misunderstand my question.  In my example you can see I have passed `:@routing_form => self` as I expect @routing_form to be assigned self before it is passed since it is the current object I am working with.

The other locals I pass such as `:controller_name => controller_name` I would like to be able to call as `self.controller_name` from within the layout.  In the standard path of rendering a view this would work; with the render_anywhere gem (now obsolete) this continued to work.  Now in Rails 5 it does not.

Comment: I think that there's some confusion about what the `self` keyword is. This isn't meant as a variable name that you can assign something to. `self` will refer to the current instance of an initialized object.

In the case of the renderer, I don't believe there's an instantiation happening, and thus there is no `self` available.

Comment: In the case of a typical render request cycle instance variables from the controller are passed back to the view during initialization. Those variables are then available on `self` which is the would be a view object. Render Anywhere simulates the same behavior when rendering a view outside the typical request cycle (in this case from a model).